# Grub failed boot detection 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2

I started my hp laptop and it started to said "press ctrl+c to cancel all filesystem checks in progress"

I waited but nothing happened. It does not show progress and caps lock for example is not working at that time. It is unresponsive.

When it was booting, i tried to press f9101112 and it opened that screwn in my picture i added but cant write anything there. I tried to reach grub but couldnot do it.

Do i need live usb? Can i make a live usv withoutformatting a harddrive and keeping files on windows pc?

[image: after preasing f1x]